# BCS and External List: Validations and Business Logic

Tags: bcs, external-list

I have been able to define an External List through a WCF Service.  This works well, but I am now moving onto more advanced scenarios - I would like my Create, Update and Delete methods to implement validations and business logic.

For example, when a list item is created, I would like to perform validations to ensure certain fields are unique across all rows in the table and enforce business rules such as "If cost field of list item > 1 million dollars and the current status of parent record in the DB is 'In Progress', prevent creation of current list item".

Can someone please provide some insight into how I can return error / business rule failure information to SharePoint?  I tried throwing an exception, but the exception message is not displayed to the user.

Comment: Great question. A real shame it hasn't been answered...